# Pagination with custom post type not working

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination

For some reason I can'g get pagination using previous_posts_link and next_posts_link working.

Here is the code I have...

```
<?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; ?>

<?php // The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query(
array(
    'post_type'=>'article',
    'posts_per_page'=>2,
    'orderby'=>'date',
    'paged'=>$paged
)
);

// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

if($the_query->current_post == 0 && $paged == 1) :
?>
<article class="latest">
    <div class="summary">
        <h4>LATEST ARTICLE:</h4>

        <h2><?=the_title(); ?></h2>
        <div class="entry-meta">
            <?php proagent_posted_on(); ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
        <div class="entry-content">
            <?=get_the_content_limit(300, 'More'); ?>

        </div><!-- .entry-content -->

        <div class="entry-topics"><?=get_the_term_list($post->ID , 'topics', 'Topics: ',', '); ?></div>
    </div>
    <?=the_post_thumbnail('feature-post-thumbnail'); ?>
</article>

<?php else: ?>
<article class="previous">
    <?=the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    <div class="summary">
        <h2><?=the_title(); ?></h2>
        <div class="entry-meta">
            <?php proagent_posted_on(); ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
        <div class="entry-content">
            <?=get_the_content_limit(300, 'More'); ?>

        </div><!-- .entry-content -->

        <div class="entry-topics"><?=get_the_term_list($post->ID , 'topics', 'Topics: ',', '); ?></div>
    </div>
</article>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<nav id="nav-below" class="navigation">
    <div class="alignleft"><?php previous_posts_link('« Newer Articles') ?></div>
    <div class="alignright"><?php next_posts_link('Older Articles »') ?></div>
</nav><!-- #nav-below -->
```

Also.. just noticed it works when I go to /articles/page/2 there is a link to /articles/ like there should be but from the /articles/ page there is no link to page 2.. WHY?

PLEASE help if you can... this is driving me crazy.

Thanks! mark.

Comment: In what context are you trying to make this work? Page template? Category template? index.php? That can have important implications for the code.

Comment: It's a custom post category template. I'm trying to show items in my custom post type called "articles" and this is the articles home page. I've defined a page, also called articles.php that I'm coding in. Any help would be very very very much appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The pagination works only, if the `paged` attribute in the the global `$wp_query` variable is set. You could store your query manually in this global or just use `query_posts()` instead of `new WP_Query()`.

```
<?php
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $the_query = query_posts(
        array(
            'post_type'=>'article',
            'posts_per_page'=>2,
            'orderby'=>'date',
            'paged'=>$paged
        )
    );
    // ...
?>
```

The function `query_posts()` will unset an existing `$wp_query` global, runs a new `WP_Query()` and stores the result again in the global `$wp_query` variable.

Comment: This is an old post. For those reading this answer, be aware that there is new information on WordPress.org. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/

Answer (score 12):

your page-slug has to be different than the custom post type name

Comment: Please post it as a comment or else explain the how it works a little bit.

Comment: Works perfect, thanks!

Comment: page-slug can be same as custom post type name: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/135146/resolve-a-custom-post-type-name-vs-page-permalink-conflict-same-slug