# Overriding default template if page slug and post type are same

Tags: template-hierarchy

I have created a post type named 'faq', and a page 'faq' for displaying the posts under faq. Also I have created a page template name faq and selected the faq page's template to this.

Now the problem is the faq page always render default template, which is `archive.php` or `index.php`. I tried to change the template name to `page-faq.php` and `page-{page_id}.php` but failed to achieve desired result.

Is there any way to override default template in this case if I would not willing to change the page slug or post type.

Comment: Your issue seems related to this http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/135146/resolve-a-custom-post-type-name-vs-page-permalink-conflict-same-slug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy way to achieve this.

```
register_post_type( 'mypost',
    array(
        ...
        'has_archive' => false,
        ...
    )
);
```

After updating this reset the permalinks 'Settings -> Permalink'

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?

Comment: Follow the documentation [wordpress.org](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)